# What does "returns iterator" mean in python?

Tags: python, iterator, networkx

I'm using networkx in Python as a functional interface to graph methods and assorted utilities. I want to create a list with all neighbours of a node in a graph.

The webpage states that all_neighbors(graph, node), returns iterator. What does that mean? How do I save the neighbours in a list?

http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.all_neighbors.html#networkx.classes.function.all_neighbors

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/9884132/989121

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterators are the new funky jazz in Python, (well not really new) they are basically an object that can be iterated over directly e.g.

```
for i in all_neighbors(graph, node):
    print i
```

So when something says it returns an iterator, it means something that can be directly iterated. But is not a list.

To get all the values of an iterator in a list, you can do `list(all_neighbors(graph, node))`

But just using it directly is far far simpler.

[Here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) is some documentation explaining iterator types.

Comment: +1 for "Iterators are the new funky jazz in Python, (well not really new)"

Answer (score 1):

An iterator is an object that provides values *one by one*, and does this just once. You can loop over an iterator, or ask for the next value with the `next()` function, but you cannot index into an iterator (ask for elements in specific locations in the sequence), for example.

You can collect all those values into a list simply by calling `list()` on the iterator:

```
list(all_neighbors(graph, node))
```